# How to get and set value using session in .net core 2.0 api

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Instead of below list. I want to fetch the Username and Password from session

private List _users = new List
        {
            new User { Id = 1, FirstName = "Jeevan", LastName = "Nigade", Username = "Jeevan", Password = "jeevan" }
        };

This is my controller Code :-

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost("token")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]User userParam)
    {
        //var user
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParam.Username))
            {
                return StatusCode(400, "Username Cannot Be Null..!!");
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParam.Password))
            {
                return StatusCode(400, "Password Cannot Be Null..!!");
            }
            else
            {
                var user = _userService.Authenticate(userParam.Username, userParam.Password);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return StatusCode(400,"Username or password is incorrect..!!");
                }

                return Ok(user);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("private")]        
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var users = _userService.GetAll();
        return Ok(users);
    }   
}
```

Below is my class UserServie.cs code :-
 public class UserService : IUserService
    {

```
    private List<User> _users = new List<User>
    {
        new User { Id = 1, FirstName = "Jeevan", LastName = "Nigade", Username = "Jeevan", Password = "jeevan" }
    };

    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public UserService(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
    }

    public User Authenticate(string username, string password)
    {

       var user = _users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password);

        if (user == null)
            return null;

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var ClientValues = _appSettings.ClientId + _appSettings.ClientSecret;
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ClientValues);
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Id.ToString())
            }),
            //Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var token  = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        user.Token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        user.Password = null;

        return user;
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
    {
        return _users.Select(x => {
            x.Password = null;
            return x;
        });
    }


}
```

where I have set the list value.

In this where and how can i set the Session value and how do i fetch it.

Comment: In this Where and How can I set the value in session and fetch that value for Username and Password. which i have included in list.Help me in this.

Comment: to fetch from `session` you need to first store in a session, without storing values you cannot access it form session. from your posted question what I have understood is username and password should be accessed instead of a `_users`  variables you need to get it from the session. make me clear if I have misunderstood.

Comment: @ArvindMaurya :- Yes, Instead of that list I want to set Username and password into session and then I have to fetch that both value . but dont know how to do it.

Comment: @ArvindMaurya :- Instead of that _user hardcoded list similar way i just want to set Username and password into session.Then I have to access it.So how to do it.so when I use postman by using method name that time it should me return that username and password which I have set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code,the user list seems to be all the users.I suggest that you could get them like below:

```
var user = _context.User.ToList();
```

For you want to set session and get it.Here is a working demo like below:

1.Controller.cs

```
public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private  IUserService _userService;
    public const string SessionKeyName = "user";
    public UsersController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost("token")]
    public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]User userParam)
    {
        var users = new User { Id = 1, FirstName = "Jeevan", LastName = "Nigade", Username = "Jeevan", Password = "jeevan" };
        HttpContext.Session.SetComplexData(SessionKeyName, users);
        var _users = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<User>(SessionKeyName);
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParam.Username))
            {
                return StatusCode(400, "Username Cannot Be Null..!!");
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userParam.Password))
            {
                return StatusCode(400, "Password Cannot Be Null..!!");
            }
            else
            {
                var user = _userService.Authenticate(userParam.Username, userParam.Password,_users);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return StatusCode(400, "Username or password is incorrect..!!");
                }

                return Ok(user);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("private")]
    public IActionResult GetAll()
    {
        var _users = HttpContext.Session.GetComplexData<User>(SessionKeyName);
        var users = _userService.GetAll(_users);
        return Ok(users);
    }
```

2.UserService:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public User Authenticate(string username, string password,User _users)
    {
        if (_users.Username == username && _users.Password == password)
            return _users;
        return null;
    }

    public User GetAll(User _users)
    {
        return _users;
    }
}
```

3.IUserService:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    User Authenticate(string username, string password,User _users);
    User GetAll(User _users);
}
```

4.SessionExtensions:

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static T GetComplexData<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var data = session.GetString(key);
        if (data == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
    }

    public static void SetComplexData(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }
}
```

5.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
        services.AddSession();
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: --> It gives me error in userservice.cs.That userservice does not implement interface member that is IUserservice.Authenticate and IUserservice.GetAll where I have user interface as below   public interface IUserService
    {
        User Authenticate(string username, string password);
        IEnumerable<User> GetAll();
    }

Comment: Yes,you also need to change your Interface.I have updated.Please check my answer.Thx.

Comment: Thanks,its working but I have one doubt. is it necessary to use list instaed of it can't I use session.SetString("Username","Jeevan")  and session.SetString("Password","jeevan") and similar way like Session.GetString("Username") and Session.GetString("Password") by using GetString to fetch that value.In this scenario

Comment: If you only have one record to store.You could try your solution,it may be more easier.If my answer worked,could you mark it and it would help others.Thanks so much!

Comment: Absolutely I have mark it.. just need one small help plese. I am sharing you link of code which I have used code. I want for single user then how can I do it please give me answe. here is link  https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api#users-controller-cs     not a single change in this code.

Comment: Will you Please  give me one more scenario for single user.

Comment: You mean you want to get one user and set them by using `session.SetString("Username","Jeevan") and session.SetString("Password","jeevan")`?Actually you just change the `List<User>` to `User` in my code is ok.

Comment: I would be glad if you give me code for single user perspective as I am new in .net core. Thanks for your help thanks alot.